# How to get custom session in rest api calls?

Tags: rest-api, session, magento2.3.0

I have created a custom session and it's storage with custom namespace.

I have set some data in storage which I am trying to fetch in my api calls but not getting any data in session.

I do get the data from session storage in storefront but not in rest api calls.

It is this preference code that doesn't allow me to access the session.

```
<preference for="Magento\Framework\Session\Config\ConfigInterface" type="Demo\MyModule\Model\Session\CustomConfig" />
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Magento Session is working with **frontend & adminhtml area. It does not work at  Rest APi**. Why you have using this session variable.Please explain

Comment: @Amit Bera : Customer session is already accessible when you call rest api in storefront. Try to call http://localhost/rest/V1/customers/me and print session in  /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/Authorization/CustomerSessionUserContext.php.

We are not able to do same with custom session.

Comment: You are wrong. I donot think .. it could be possiable

Comment: @AmitBera : Have you tried what I mentioned in my previous comment. Please do not comment based on assumption.

Comment: @Sanjoy, I will cross check it  . Might be  have area set  frontend when you  have to send request from  rest API

Comment: I have figured out the problem that I have added session namespace by creating a preference on \Magento\Framework\Session\Config\ConfigInterface. If I remove this preference I am able to access the session in api calls but by removing this preference my session expires when customer logs out which I don't want. So need to find a way to access session with different name. I have added my code for reference.